# pyinstaller --onefile doesn't copy necessary file

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, exe, pyinstaller

Recently I've made a GUI application with PyQT5 in python3 and this app is included Images and musics.
my source code run properly, but when I use this command :

```
pyinstaller --onefile GUI.py
```

to make .exe file, my application doesn't run properly and when I copy the Images and musics beside my .exe it works properly.
I want to know how can I to make .exe with pyinstaller with my data files in it and I want that my data file's isn't shown at all.

Answer (score -1):

Add file directory in the file `GUI.spec` following instructions [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle)

Then delete all the folders created by pyinstaller, **EXCEPT** `GUI.spec`

Type in terminal: `pyinstaller GUI.spec`
(notice: this time `.spec`, not `.py`)